Почему отсутствует запятая между повторяющимися союзами?
Цитата из романа «Братья Карамазовы» Достоевского:

...значит, для этого-то брата, может быть, и отсылал его от себя и вчера и сегодня.

И вчера и сегодня
Очень часто встречаю случаи употребления повторяющегося союза и… и без разделения их запятой. Подскажите, пожалуйста, для этой ситуации есть какое-то правило?
Почему запятая отсутствует?

     И вчера, и сегодня
     Билась ветка рябины
     Птицей робко в окно.


Краткая теория

Повторяющийся союз И...И и одиночный союз И относятся к соединительным союзам, но какая между ними разница? Сравним:
У тебя когда тренировка? — Сегодня и завтра.
У тебя когда тренировка, сегодня или завтра? — И сегодня, и 
завтра. 

Повторяющийся союз подчеркивает значимость каждого однородного члена и обычно используется, когда появляются сомнения. Интонация перечислительная.
У тебя когда тренировка, сегодня или завтра? — И сегодня и 
завтра, в оба дня. 

При отсутствии запятой первый союз И приравнивается к усилительной частице, тогда второй союз И является одиночным.  В этом случае у нас единая конструкция, подчеркивающая смысловую связь двух однородных членов (возможна замена: и зимой и летом — всегда). Оборот произносится  одну фонетическую фразу, без паузы.

Правило Розенталя определяет потенциальную возможность двух вариантов для союза И...И (часто для антонимов, синонимов и слов с ассоциативными связями),  но выбор в конечном итоге делается для конкретного примера с учетом семантики и интонационной структуры предложения в целом и оборота речи в частности.

Правильно:


«…значит, для этого-то брата, может быть, и отсылал его от себя и вчера и сегОдня».
Слова сегодня и завтра связаны между собой по смыслу, и на практике мы видим оба варианта постановки знаков. Отметим, что в конце простого предложения обычно находится оборот и сегодня и завтра как единая фонетическая конструкция, на которую падает ударение.

Примеры из литературы

Ф. М. Достоевский.
Слушайте, Алексей Федорович, почему вы такой грустный все эти дни, и вчера и сегОдня.
А. П. Чехов.
Каждый день получаю. И вчерА, и сегОдня. Этот дикий человек опять заболел, опять с ним нехорошо...
О. Мандельштам. Пробовал и вчерА, и сегОдня себя перечитывать, и, ей-ей, лучше, хотя, может быть, схематичнее.
Г. П. Зайцева. Дневник (1981).
Но ведь все и вчера и сегОдня произошло из за него.
Сергей Залыгин.
И звонил Асе и вчера и сегОдня — безответно.

Запятые при однородных членах предложения, соединенных повторяющимися союзами
При двух однородных членах предложения с повторяющимся союзом и запятая не ставится, если образуется тесное смысловое единство (обычно такие однородные члены не имеют при себе пояснительных слов): Кругом было и светло и зелено (Т.); Он носил и лето и зиму старую жокейскую кепку (Пауст.); Прибрежная полоса, пересечённая мысами, уходила и в ту и в другую сторону (Сем.); Он был и весел и печален в одно и то же время.
Такие смысловые единства образуются словами с ассоциативными (часто антонимическими) связями: и брат и сестра; и родители и дети; и отцу и матери; и с сыном и с дочерью; и друзья и враги; и слава и позор; и зрение и слух; и тело и душа; и глухой и немой; и море и горы; и музыка и пение; и стихи и проза; и любовь и ненависть; и радость и горе; и зимой и летом; и ножи и вилки; и блюдца и чашки; и он и она.
